# Highlighting substrings in print statements

Tags: python, regex, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have been trying to write a short script to be run directly in jupyter notebook. It simply scrolls through texts (400 words on avg.) in pandas df and asks user for a label.

I am struggling with finding an elegant solution that would highlight all substrings 'eu' in the text to be printed out.

In an other thread, I have found this printmd function that I use to highlight the "eu" substring. However, this only works for the first appearance and breaks the lines as well.

```py
import sys
from IPython.display import clear_output
from IPython.display import Markdown, display

def printmd(string):
    display(Markdown(string))
printmd('**bold**')

labels = []

for i in range(0,len(SampleDf)):

    clear_output() # clear the output before displaying another article
    print(SampleDf.loc[i]['article_title'])

    lc = SampleDf.loc[i]['article_body'].lower() # the search is case sensitive
    pos = lc.find('eu') # where is the 'eu' mentioned

    print(SampleDf.loc[i]['article_body'][:pos])
    printmd('**eu**')

    print(SampleDf.loc[i]['article_body'][pos+2:])

    var = input("press y if the text is irrelevant" )

    if var == 'y':
        label = 0   # 0 for thrash
    else: 
        label = 1   # 1 for relevant

    labels.append(label)
```

I would love to get rid of the line breaks introduced by the separate print statements and highlight all mentions of the "eu".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this as string processing, not an output problem.  If I'm understanding your needs properly, this is a simple `replace` usage:

```
new_text = old_text.replace("eu", "**eu**")
```

If you still need your single-token mode, then
suppressing a line feed is a simple matter of using the `print` parameter for that purpose:

```
print('**eu**', end='')
```

Comment: @DivyanshuSrivastava What SO question holds your [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?